# SimpleXMLElement parsing issue with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to parse out the following response:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [responseType] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [inputConceptName] => aspirin [inputKindName] => % ) 
    [groupConcepts] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [concept] => Array ( 
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                [conceptName] => ASPIRIN 
                [conceptNui] => N0000145918 
                [conceptKind] => DRUG_KIND ) 
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( #
                [conceptName] => Aspirin 
                [conceptNui] => N0000006582 
                [conceptKind] => INGREDIENT_KIND ) 
) ) )
```

in PHP.  I have it stored as a curl string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml);
```

How do I get just the conceptNui of the first object as a PHP variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation, it give simple example to understand the friendly syntax to extract the data :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

In your case, it could be :

```
$xml->groupConcepts->concept[0]->conceptNui
```

As your structure is

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [responseType] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [inputConceptName] => aspirin 
    [inputKindName] => % ) 
  [groupConcepts] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [concept] => Array ([0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                    [conceptName] => ASPIRIN 
                    [conceptNui] => N0000145918 
                    [conceptKind] => DRUG_KIND ) 
              [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                    [conceptName] => Aspirin 
                    [conceptNui] => N0000006582 
                    [conceptKind] => INGREDIENT_KIND ) 
              )
          )
  )
```

Comment: I think you're answer is right, just trying to iron out the last piece.  How do I get the last part to be an actual PHP variable? $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);     

$data = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data); 
$xml->groupConcepts->concept[0]->conceptNui;

Comment: `$conceptNui = $xml->groupConcepts->concept[0]->conceptNui;` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   $conceptNui = $mainObj->groupConcepts->concept[0]->conceptNui;
```